# How to save rows of selected products and its qty to a MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have an html table with rows of products. A user can tick a checkbox to select a product from the list and enter its quantity. User can select row 1 and input its qty, row 3 and inpiut its qty or row 6 and input its qty. i can save the product id, but i cannot save the qty entered by the user. How can i save the rows of products selected and its qty to a MySQL DB?

This is how i list the products and its inputbox:

```
while($iGroups < count($listeProduct))
{
 ?> 
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="checkbox" name="productSelect[]" id="productSelect_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>" value="" <?php echo $checkedProduct; ?> ><?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_NAME; ?>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="productQty[]" id="productQty_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>" size="45" maxlength="100" class="form-control1" value="" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php
 $iGroups++;
}
?>
```

In the controller this is how i deal with the $_POST after submit.
How to get the qty enter by user in the input box? :

```
$producySelected = $_POST['docSelect'];
$productQty = $_POST['comboNumDoc'];

$icount = 0;
while($icount < count($producySelected))
{
    $PRODUCT_ID = $productSelected[$icount]->product_id;
    $QTY = ??

    $icount ++; 
}
```

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: You could simply use product id in the names of the input fields, so that they would be dynamically structured as "productQty-ID". Then you can easily get the values in your controller loop with `$_POST['productQty-'.$PRODUCT_ID]`

Comment: could you please give me an example of what you mean...thanks kaarto

Comment: It's basicly the same thing what you currently do to input id's, do the same thing to input names. Then `var_dump($_POST) ;` after submit and you'll see how it works

Comment: thanks man for replying, im in a jam, is this what u mean: <input type="text"  name="productQty-<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>[]" id="productQty<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>" size="45" maxlength="100" class="form-control1" value="<?php echo $DOC_CLIENT_NUM;}?>" tabindex="2"/>

Comment: Yes, but no need for []. I'm on my phone, so can't give straight example, but you'll get it once you try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add productId at input field name then you can get the value on the basic of product_id like below.

```
while($iGroups < count($listeProduct))
    {
     ?> 
     <tr>
     <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="productSelect[<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>]['product_id']" id="productSelect_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>" value="" <?php echo $checkedProduct; ?> ><?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_NAME; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="productSelect[<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>]['quantity']" id="productQty_<?php echo $listeDoc[$iGroups]->PRODUCT_ID ?>" size="45" maxlength="100" class="form-control1" value="" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     $iGroups++;
    }
    ?>
```

In your controller you get the value like this ..

```
    $producySelected = $_POST['productSelect']; 
  if(!empty($producySelected){

    foreach($producySelected as $key=>$selected){
    {
        $PRODUCT_ID = $selected['product_id'];
        $QTY = $selected['quantity'];

    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks Rakesh. in the controller i cant get the product_id and qty. it give me an Undefined index: product_id. Could you please help out this last part...im really really in a jam...many thanks

Comment: can you please post here your posted data here ... out put of print_r($_POST); 
what form data you are submitting.

Comment: @KevinDave i have tested it at my end. And its working fine. There may be some issue in your form data. Please send me you data $_POST

Comment: this is my $_POST = array(2) {
  [1101]=>
  array(2) {
    ["'product_id'"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["'quantity'"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [901]=>
  array(2) {
    ["'product_id'"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["'quantity'"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}

Comment: And this is what im trying out:

  $producySelected = $_POST['productSelect']; 
  if(!empty($producySelected))
  {
   foreach($producySelected as $key=>$selected)
   {
    //$PRODUCT_ID = $selected['product_id'];
    //$QTY = $selected['quantity'];
    
    $PRODUCT_ID = $key;
    echo ('PRODUCT_ID :'.$PRODUCT_ID);
    echo("<br>");
    
    foreach($selected as $key=>$select)
    {
     print_r($select);
     echo("<br>");
     
     //echo ('QTY: '.$select);
     //echo $QTY;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: ooouuuff....many many thanks Rakesh and Kaarto....i managed to get the quantity.

$QTY = $selected["'quantity'"];

Comment: @KevinDave if this was even bit helpful for you. Please remove down vote. thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant seem to upvote your answer. i get this message: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Howerver, i sincerely say a big thanks to you Rakesh.